# Taking print out of jQuery flot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, graph, flot

I am using jQuery flot graph and want to take the print out (or at least the image) of the graph. Now, before asking this question I did lot of research to find out a way..and I come up with this question on stack overflow.

**[How to print flot graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242455/how-to-print-flot-graph)**

I implemented the technique given there.

Now, I am able to get the image of the graph but I am not able to get the contents of the graph i.e. I am just getting plain background of the canvas and not the area drawn over it.

The images below will explain this clearly:

***This is what my graph looks like...***
[image: This is what my graph looks like...]

***And this is what I am getting after coverting it to image:***
[image]

I am using the `ToDataUrl` for coversion and below is my code:

```
  var somePlot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ [0,0],[10,10] ]);
  var canvas = somePlot.getCanvas();
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

**In the code above:**

`somePlot` variable is for fetching the canvas which is inside the `div` as `jquery flot` implements the graph inside a canvas which I was not able to access directly using its `id`.

Any help will be appreciated, Thankyou...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not converting your graph to an image, but some testgraph which is empty. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP2Zp/1/) (the top graph is made with plot, the bottom one is the image).

If you fix your test data you get this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP2Zp/), which shows the graph both in the plot part and the image. Fixing the data here means inserting more brackets:

```
var somePlot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ [ [0,0], [10,10] ] ]);
```

PS: My tests don't use the plugin to add the labels to the canvas, but from your image I see you already got that part right.

Comment: Thank you very much @Raidri ...I was doing it completely wrong. Now I have corrected the errors..Thanks again for the fiddle and explanation :)

Comment: Is there a method to print the axis description too?

Comment: @nagazi Are you using the [canvas plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/canvas/index.html)? Then it should work out of the box. For alternative solutions see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18136509/2610249).