# Html page print with flot graphs

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, flot

[image]I have a coldfusion page which spits out a report which has data and flot graphs in it. How do I go about print this page without the graphs breaking. I looked up and only saw how only the graph can be exported as an image and be printed. I want the whole page to be printed with unbroken graphs. Any ideas here?

Comment: the graph is printable, got a valid css for print?

Comment: here a solution to generate image from svg, http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1903884&seqNum=9

Comment: and a stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242455/how-to-print-flot-graph

Comment: I have seen these, I want the whole page not only the graph. Hope this helps

Comment: i dont understand, when a i show print page works fine http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/multiple-axes.html

Comment: I have added the report screen shot's print preview which shows how the graph gets broken. Any idea how to fix that

Comment: @Álvaro Touzón any thoughts ?

Comment: hi, this is not a problem of flot, i belive there is no space in first page and split it into two pages, reduce the height of the graph or givre more space before to add all in rhe two page