# How to export Flot Chart graph to an image including the legend and the title

Tags: php, flot

My objective is to export the title, to png.

To export graphs, the only way we found is to serialize the $.plot call into a php serialized array and save it in the database.

Here is an example of what I would like to include in the canvas.
Actually, only the graph is included.

[image]

I found and used this:
https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/36
https://github.com/flot/flot/pull/42
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/canvas/index.html

It helps with the legend but not for everything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I've had great success with using phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org/) server-side.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? php?

Comment: Yes the data comes from PHP, from a MySQL database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FLOT data as image to write to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646897/flot-data-as-image-to-write-to-pdf)